# My JQuery is running in a loop. Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

Here is my code,

```
 $('#code').change(function() {
     $('select[name="country_code"]').on('change', function() {
        var countryCode = $('#code').val();
        console.log(countryCode);
      $('select[name="country"]').prop("disabled", false);
        $('select[name="country"]').val(countryCode).trigger('change');

    });
 });



$('#country').change(function() {
     $('select[name="country"]').on('change', function() {
      var countryName = $('#country').val();
      console.log(countryName);
      $('select[name="country_code"]').prop("disabled", false);
      $('select[name="country_code"]').val(countryName).trigger('change');
    });
 });
```

The country should automatically get fetched and show in select option when I change the Country code. This is working perfectly, but When I console this is running endlessly and an error "**Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**" coming.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Can you please share your HTML as well?

Comment: I have 2 dropdowns. One is country code select (id: code), another one is country select (id: country)

Comment: Problem 1) You should not add event handlers inside event handlers.  It means, for eg, that every time `#code` changes, you add *another* copy of that same event handler on your select - they just double up.  **All** of them will then run when triggered.

Problem 2) You haven't shown us your HTML, but if the selector on either of your the event handlers set inside other event handlers will also match the selector on the outside selector, you'll get a recursive loop.

Answer (score 0):

try to put this event outside:

```js
$('select[name="country"]').on('change', function() {
      var countryName = $('#country').val();
      console.log(countryName);
      $('select[name="country_code"]').prop("disabled", false);
      $('select[name="country_code"]').val(countryName).trigger('change');
    });
```

after that use trigger function to call the event:

```js
$('#country').change(function() {
     $('select[name="country"]').trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: is the element #country generated by javascript code?